# how to get pebble watch time is 12h or 24h use api ?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I just saw it in the example project. But I removed it. I can't find it or the example.
I just want get the api for check 24h or 12h in locate.

Answer (score 0):

found it in pebble official doc page "wall time"

bool clock_is_24h_style(void);

https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/Wall_Time/